# How do I connect my dd-wrt router to another wireless network and ensure that all my clients connect only to the dd-wrt?

Tags: networking, routing, router, wlan

Here's my situation: I have my internet connection provided by a wireless network (we'll call it "A").  I don't have a lot of control over that network, though.  I have a wrt610n flashed with dd-wrt, and I'd like to use it as my main router/connection point to that network.  I'm fairly sure I need to setup at least one of the antennas as a "client" to network A.  I've tried this, it works fine, I get a WAN IP on the router.  However, now I'd like to turn around and offer another network (we'll call it "B") for my devices to connect to.  And, that means both wired and wireless devices.  Can someone help me figure out how to configure it to do this?

Comment: Or does this belong over on SU?

Comment: Probably more appropriate for there, looks like home use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in DD-WRT by setting up a wireless repeater. Essentially you connect your AP as a client to the network (as you've done) and then create a sub-interface on the router which broadcasts a different SSID. That is connected to the internal interfaces of the router enabling you to manage the broadcast network.

The docs on this are pretty comprehensive so there isn't much point in me going through this blow by blow, have a look here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater

Anecdotally I used this to great effect with an 18dB omni directional antenna attached to a WRT54GL while camping in Europe.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a try.  The example in the introduction really sounds like it's a match.  It does not specifically address wired connections though; I wonder if that will be tricky.

Comment: Missed the wired bit, those would just plug into the LAN ports on the router (those are also connected to the LAN side of the router and get the same network as your new virtual interface).

Comment: Ok, so I tried it, but not getting LAN routing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: LAN as in wired, or it's not working wired or wireless? You might need to check that the switch is bridged with the correct interface on the router in Setup->VLANs.

Comment: Ok, I got it.  I believe I was missing the fact that I had been setting it to "Router" mode rather than leaving it on "Gateway".  Thanks for the help.